# How to match counter and object?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
public counter = 0;

x0: any; x1: any; x2: any; x3: any; x4: any;

next(){
  this.counter += 1;
  this.storage.set("Count", this.counter);
  console.log(this.counter);
  this.logic();
}

logic(){
  //automatic counter here
  var xNum = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("x" + this.counter));
  xNum = true;
}
```

I have 5 items: X0-X5.
I would like to set them true, like this one:
this.X1=true;

While I do not want to do it manually, I would like the tap counter to do it for me.
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just use an array instead? `x: any[];` `x[this.counter] = true`

Comment: Why is it any and not boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to define an object.

```
data = {
    'x1': false,
    'x2': false ...
}

for (let d in this.data) {
   let str = 'x2' // let say you want to edit this one.
   if (d === 'x2') {
      this.data[d] = true;
   }
}
```